# Javascript regular expression to validate whether both () brackets are present

Tags: javascript, regex

Techies,

I'm working on kind of calculator, am not much comfortable with regex. My need is JavaScript regular expression to validate whether both ( ) brackets are present, there may be some character inside the brackets.

suggestions please

Comment: show us what have you tried, we are not here to do free work

Comment: Thanks Nikhil for your kind words. this is the expression I have tried var exp = /^(\(\d{3}\)/

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex:

```js
var string = '1234 + 1234 (5)';
if (string.match('\(|\)')) {
    console.log('() found')
}
```

Comment: This just checks if any bracket is present - no matter wether they are balanced or not. It is neither suited to check if correctly used brackets are present nor is it suited to check if unbalanced brackets are present.

Comment: Thanks Aldrin, its not working for below string 
var string = '1234 + 1234 (5'

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. Does it have to be regex though?

Comment: yeah Aldrin, I need it as regex

Answer (score 0):

Simply matching

```
\(.*\)
```

will match if both an opening, and a closing parentheses are present. (Parentheses need to be escaped since it's a special character in regex.) `.*` matches anything, including an empty string.

But I assume you'd want to allow strings without any parentheses as well. This regex allows for any number of pairs of parentheses (**not nested**) or none at all:

```
^[^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*$
```

It matches *start of string* `^`, a string of any length **not** containing parentheses `[^()]*`. Then any number of the combination 1. Opening P(arentheses) 2. Any length string w/o P's. 3. A closing P. 4. Any length string w/o P's. (Possibly repeated any number of times.) Finally it matches *end of string* `$`.

Working example (Type an expression into the input control, and press `Enter`.):

```js
var inputExpression = document.getElementById("expression");

function testExpression(){
    console.log(inputExpression.value.match(/^[^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*$/) ? "Well formed" : "Unbalanced parentheses");
//    inputExpression.value = '';
}


inputExpression.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        testExpression();
    }
});
```

```html
Enter an expression:<input id="expression" type="text" onBlur="testExpression()"/>
```